# HTML character entity replacement in R

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing, character, replace

I have a large set of HTML files that contain text from a magazine in nodes `span`. My PDF to HTML converter inserted the character entity `&nbsp;` throughout the HTML. The problem is that in R, I use the `xmlValue` function (in XML package) to extract the text but wherever there was a `&nbsp;` the space between the words is eliminated. For example:

```
<span class="ft6">kids,&nbsp;and kids in your community,&nbsp;in                                   DIY&nbsp;projects.&nbsp;</span>
```

will come out of the `xmlValue` function as:

```
"kids,and kids in your community,in DIYprojects."
```

I was thinking that the easiest way to resolve this would be to find all `&nbsp;` before running the `span` nodes through `xmlValue`, and replace them with a `" "` (space). How would I approach that?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22157168/1548942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have re-written the answer to reflect the problem of the original poster not being able to get text from an `XMLValue`. There's probably different ways to tackle this but one way is to just to directly open/replace/write the HTML files themselves. Generally tackling XML/HTML with regexes is A Bad Idea but in this case we have a straightforward problem of unwanted non-breaking spaces, so it's likely not too much of an issue. The following code is an example of how to create a list of matching files and perform a `gsub` on the contents. It should be easy to modify or expand as needed.

```
setwd("c:/test/")
# Create 'html' file to use with test
txt <- "<span class=ft6>kids,&nbsp;and kids in your community,&nbsp;in                                   DIY&nbsp;projects.&nbsp;</span>
<span class=ft6>kids,&nbsp;and kids in your community,&nbsp;in                                   DIY&nbsp;projects.&nbsp;</span>
<span class=ft6>kids,&nbsp;and kids in your community,&nbsp;in                                   DIY&nbsp;projects.&nbsp;</span>"
writeLines(txt, "file1.html")

# Now read files - in this case only one
html.files <- list.files(pattern = ".html")
html.files

# Loop through the list of files
retval <- lapply(html.files, function(x) {
          in.lines <- readLines(x, n = -1)
          # Replace non-breaking space with space
          out.lines <- gsub("&nbsp;"," ", in.lines)
          # Write out the corrected lines to a new file
          writeLines(out.lines, paste("new_", x, sep = ""))
})
```

Comment: It is `&nbsp;` not `$nbsp` by the way, so `gsub("&nbsp;"," ",test)` should work.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for spotting that - typos now fixed. Must avoid posting before waking up properly...

Comment: I have tried gsub. The problem is that the input to the xmlValue is not a character vector, it is an "XMLinternalNode." The gsub needs either something convertible to a character vector or a character vector, neither of which is true.