# Unescape HTML &#nn; sequences

Tags: r

My text has some HTML escaped characters, for instance, instead of `'` there is `&#39;`. Now I would like to unescape these sequences. Since I do not know which characters are escaped, I do not want to use a simple mapping such as in  `c("&#39;"="'", ...)`.

I understand that the number after the ampersand is the decimal unicode number. So `&#39;` is `\u27` since 27 is the hexidecimal representation of 39. So I thought a solution that involves

```
sprintf("\u%x", s)
```

where `s` is the extracted number between `&` and `;`. However, this results in an error: "\u used without hex numbers."

What would be a better approach to convert HTML escaped sequences back to characters?

Comment: Does [this link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/321478.html) help?

Comment: A little bit, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for reference, here is the solution I came up with. It makes use of the great package `gsubfn`:

```
library(gsubfn)
```

I use a vector `htmlchars` for named html entities I scraped from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). For brevity, I do not copy the vector in this answer here, but source it from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XtzN1NMs):

```
source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XtzN1NMs") # creates variable htmlchars
```

Now the decoding function I was looking for is simply:

```
strdehtml <- function(s) {
    ret <- gsubfn("&#([0-9]+);", function(x) rawToChar(as.raw(as.numeric(x))), s)
    ret <- gsubfn("&([^;]+);", function(x) htmlchars[x], ret)
    return(ret)
}
```

Not sure if this covers all possible HTML characters, but it gets me working.
For instance, it can be used thus:

```
test <- "My this &amp; last year&#39;s resolutions"
strdehtml(test)
[1] "My this & last year's resolutions"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also call Node.JS from R as a system command. Node.JS has packages which do exactly this. Here are the instructions:

1. Install Node.JS and NPM `apt-get install nodejs npm`
2. Install html-entities package `npm install html-entities`
3. Call Node.JS from R

`print(system(command = "nodejs -e \"var Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities; entities = new Entities(); console.log(entities.decode('&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;&copy;&reg;&#8710;'));\""))`

Here is the output from the above command

`<>"'&©®∆`